# constructor vs destructor environment assemble

Tags: c++, constructor, destructor

> A constructor assembles the execution environment for the member
> functions for a class from the bottom up (members first). The
> destructor disassembles it from the top down (members last).
>
> [from C++ programming language]

please can someone describe this? I understand that members functions means here members functions of the class, but what "members" first? is this related to function on the stack? what means "assembles the execution environment"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sentence is quite abstract. The execution environment of a a *member function* are the members of the class itself and members exposed by one of the base-classes.

Presumably, what is meant by "assemble the execution environment", is to initialize all members and bases of the class (note that member functions don't need to be initialized).

I don't see how this would relate to an object being on the stack or not.

An example:

```
class X {
public:
  X() // constructor initializes first a, then b, then c
  {
    // members are now accessible for member functions
    foo();
  }

  void foo() {
    // member function executes in the context of an object
    // a, b, and c mean this->a, this->b and this->
    std::cout << a << b << c << std::endl;
  }

  ~X() {} // destroys first c, then b and then a 
private:
  int a;
  double b;
  char c;
};
```

Please note that you don't need to write out the destructor in the
above case. This is just done for exemplary purposes here.

Comment: Note that "the member functions don't need initialization" isn't entirely true. Virtual members DO need initialization or they cannot be called. Actually, you can see the effect being talked about by calling a virtual function from within a contructor of a sub-class. Class A derives from class B, then calling B::func() assuming that func() is a virtual function should call A::func(), but that's not the case when running B::B() because func() is still just a pointer to B::func(), not yet a pointer to A::func(). Similarly, in B::~B() calling B::func() doesn't call A::func()!

Comment: @AlexisWilke Good point, I was afraid of bringing that up here, because it makes things more confusing.

Answer (score 6):

It means that in a constructor, the member sub-objects of the class are constructed first, and then the body of the constructor is run.  With the destructor, it's the opposite.  First the body of the destructor runs, and then the member sub-objects are destroyed.

The "execution environment for the member functions" is simply the environment in which the member functions can be called with defined behavior.  That environment is one where the the member sub-objects are valid constructed objects.  So to "assemble the execution environment for the member functions", is to run the constructor.  It's just flowery language.

Comment: no. it is true, but it is described almost word in word as you said in the book. then this additional info is added about assemble. so this is something more

Comment: @cf16: construct=assemble, destruct=destroy=disassemble

Comment: I don't think there is equality. I think it might be confusing. what reason to first state exactly how it is going, and then rewrite it using "assemble" in place of construct

Comment: @cf16 The description using `assemble` and `disassemble` is a lot more abstract and probably intended to give a higher level view. There is no such thing as an execution context mentioned in the language specification.

Comment: exactly, but this is not poem but book about programming. for me it could be confusing, because I start to mull out what assemble does author mean, so maybe assembly and layout on the stack - this is what I was considering

Answer (score 0):

I think that "members" means variables, so when a constructor is called on a class, it first creates the variables , then setup the environment for the execution functions of the class objects, because they may depend on the member variables.

"Assemble the execution environment" of functions mean that the member variables are initialized first, so they could be called in member functions.

While destructor first destroys the environment for all the functions of the class object and then destroys the member variables.